# How to enable systemd collector in docker-compose.yml file for node exporter

Tags: docker-compose, prometheus

Hi I 'm new to prometheus I have a task to make prometheus show systemd services metrics (I use grafana for visualization) I' m using stefanprodan/dockprom example as my starting point however I couldn't find how to enable systemd collector for node exporter in the node exporter section of the docker-compose.yml and also leave all the enabled by default collectors. Also I need help with getting that info to be sent into grafana. I would appreciate the code in the example  or a place where I could find an adequate explanation how to do it like for dummies because I'm not experienced. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, it seems like the scope of what you need is pretty broad, maybe it will help others understand your needs if you separate the post in introduction/questions.

Answer (score 2):

In order to enable the systemd collector in node_exporter, the command line flag `--collector.systemd` needs to be passed to the exporter ([reference](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/blob/master/README.md#disabled-by-default)). The default collectors will remain enabled, so you don't need to worry about that.

In order to pass that flag to the application, you need to add that flag to the `command` portion of the `nodeexporter` section of the Docker Compose file ([here](https://github.com/stefanprodan/dockprom/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L59))

In regards to sending the data to Grafana, as long as you have your Prometheus data source configured in Grafana, those metrics will show up automatically -- you don't need to update your Prometheus->Grafana when or removing metrics (or really ever, after initial setup).

Comment: when I add --collector.systemd to the docker-compose file- the dashboard in grafana shows nothing at all but when I remove this option the dashboard shows the default stats normally - CPU, memory etc. Maybe it should be written like --collector.systemd=enabled?

Comment: By the way when I launch the default stefanprodan/dockprom project on my machine all the default dashboards are working fine, but when I tried your option the dashboard for host system metrics shows nothing. Hope You could help with this mystery

Comment: It should not need anything else besides that flag. This is the command I use to run my node_exporters and you can see that it just says `--collector.systemd`:
```/usr/local/bin/node_exporter \
    --web.listen-address 0.0.0.0:9100 \
    --collector.filesystem.ignored-fs-types=^(sys|proc|auto)fs$ \
    --collector.filesystem.ignored-mount-points=^/(sys|proc|dev)($|/) \
    --collector.systemd \
    --no-collector.logind \
    --no-collector.ntp \
    --collector.textfile.directory=/opt/prometheus/textfile_collector```

Comment: I'm guessing that for some reason the node_exporter is failing to start when you add the option? You'll need to look into the docker logs for that container (something like `docker logs nodeexporter`). You can also see on the Prometheus dashboard (e.g. localhost:9090/targets) whether or not that scrape target reports as down.